# Is there ways to show a logo in many pages php?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I already write a code logo/img on header.php

but, when I going to refresh, a logo doesn't want to show up.

Is there a solution?

I used a bootstrap 4, simple html and css. I've tried many times but always fail.

In any features, a logo already show, but in "tambahalternatif" doesn't want to show

> and here is my controller :

```
<?php

    class Alternatif extends CI_Controller{

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('Alternatif_model');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

        }

        public function index()
        {

            $data ['judul'] = 'Isi Alternatif';
            $data ['alternatif'] = $this->Alternatif_model->getAllAlternatif();


            if($this->input->post('key')){
                $data['alternatif'] = $this->Alternatif_model->cariDataAlternatif();
            }


            $data['hasil'] = $this->Hitung(); //Manggil fungsi Hitung() 

            $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('alternatif/index', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer' );

        }


        public function tambahalternatif()
        {
            $data['judul'] = 'Form Tambah Data Alternatif';


            // $this->form_validation->set_rules('idclient','ID','required|numeric');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('namaalt','NAMA','required');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('alternatif/tambahalternatif');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {
            $this->Alternatif_model->tambahDataAlternatif();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash','Berhasil');
            redirect('alternatif'); 
        }
```

> header view

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-fixed-top ml-right">
<div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand" href="<?=base_url(); ?>" ><img class="logo" src="./img/logo.png" height="28px;" padding="2px 10px;></a>
```

i expect a image(logo) will show in "tambahalternatif", but image(logo) only show in "alternatif" only

Comment: Use the `<?=base_url();?>` in image `src` in header. like `<img class="logo" src="<?=base_url();?>img/logo.png" height="28px;" padding="2px 10px;>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in the header

```
<body>
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>imag/logo.png" height="28px" alt="">  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use base bath instead of absolute path.

replace

```
<img class="logo" src="./img/logo.png" height="28px;" padding="2px 10px;>
```

with below line

```
<img class="logo" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/logo.png" height="28px;" padding="2px 10px;>
```

So that when you change your view's path, the logo's path will no need to change.

Answer (score 1):

```
***Try this one & let us know is it ok now.
Thanks.***

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar- 
fixed-top ml-right">

<div class="container">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?= base_url(); ?>" >
        <img class="logo" src="<?= base_url().'img/logo.png'; ?>" 
        height="28px" padding="2px 10px">
    </a>

</div>

</nav>
```